# How to set timer to a css attribute

Tags: jquery

I am trying to add timer to background to just show empty input boxes.
or if user adds a number in it can dissappear.

```
if (!$("form input[span2]").val()) {
  $('.span2:empty').css("background", "rgb(255,220,200)");
  alert('Please fill empty fields');
}
else {......... }
```

Comment: What's your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you mean that you want the background color to disappear after a delay you can use `setTimeout()`. I would also suggest using classes to apply the styling as it makes the logic simpler. Try this:

```
if(!$("form input[span2]").val()) {
  $('.span2:empty').addClass('error');
  alert('Please fill empty fields');

  setTimeout(function() {
    $('.span2:empty').removeClass('error');
  }, 3000); // 3 second timer, amend as required
} else {
  // valid logic here...
}
```

```css
.error {
  background: rgb(255, 220, 200);
}
```

Also note that your jQuery selector implies the element has a non-standard `span2` attribute. I would advise against using non-standard attributes as they can cause some odd behaviour. Use `data` attributes to store custom metadata with an element instead.

Answer (score 0):

If you literally just want a timer, that's what `setTimeout` can achieve.

```
setTimeout(functionToExecute, time);
```

Your code is the function to execute. So it would look like this:

```
setTimeout(function(){
  if(!$("form input[span2]").val())
    {
      $('.span2:empty').css( "background", "rgb(255,220,200)" );
      alert('Please fill empty fields');
    }
    else{.........}
}, 5000);
```

Answer (score 0):

**setTimeout** is a native JavaScript function (although it can be used with a library such as jQuery, as we’ll see later on), which calls a function or executes a code snippet after a specified delay (in milliseconds). This might be useful if, for example, you wished to display a popup after a visitor has been browsing your page for a certain amount of time, or you want a short delay before removing a hover effect from an element (in case the user accidentally moused out).

Eg:

```
function explode(){
  alert("Boom!");
}
setTimeout(explode, 2000);
```

A variable that refers to a function:

```
var explode = function(){
  alert("Boom!");
};
setTimeout(explode, 2000);
```

or

```
setTimeout(function(){alert("Boom!");}, 2000);
```